# YouTube Data API V3 - Search quota points vs maxResult

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am reviewing the YouTube Data API specifically for [search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#apps-script) endpoint which says each call cost 100 points. Currently in our implementation we do infinite scroll with pagination support and do not specify `maxResult` thus default is 5 items. We are hitting the 10k quota limit frequently so we are thinking of increasing the `maxResult` up to 25 or 50 which is the maximum. The question is, does increasing the max result count will also cost us the same number of points? if we set 50 in `maxResult` param will it consume 5k points as well or only 100 points? I cannot find this idea in the documentation but if we are to take what is in the page literally it should only consume 100 points regardless of how many items `maxResult` has? However I am getting confused on this line `Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive`, what does inclusive means here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quota cost is incured every time you make a request to the API.

If there are 50 rows, and you have it set to 5 that's 10 requests you will need to make to get all of the data. or 100 * 10 = 1000 quota points.

If you just set it to 50 thats one request and you will need to make and it will cost you 100 points.

Remember the 10k quota limit is the development quota when you are ready to go to production you should request a quota extension.

Comment: So making one search request where `maxResult` is set to 50 will only cost 100 points right? Just realized my calculation above is incorrect, you are right it is 100 * 10 if maxResult is not specified.

Comment: Yes exactly.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc

Comment: what does inclusive even mean and why does it accept 0 as maxResult?

Comment: Ours is not to wonder why.   Dont ask yourself those kinds of questions it just leads to gray hair.